# Sql Alchemy for Subquery

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to transfer this mysql query into sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM library WHERE MATCH (title)  AGAINST ('**INPUT**' IN boolean MODE) LIMIT 500) 
as t WHERE title LIKE '{**INPUT**}%'"
```

This is what I got so far, but not what I expected:

```
query.filter(title.match(**INPUT**)).filter(title.like(**INPUT**)).limit(500).all()
```

Can you suggest how to implement a subquery for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found without subquery:

```
query.filter(title.match(**INPUT**)).limit(500).from_self().filter(title.like(**INPUT**)).all()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).